# External GPU through expresscard slot - Power up PSU

Tags: power-supply, gpu, expresscard

I got one of these:

http://www.banggood.com/EXP-GDC-Laptop-External-PCI-E-Graphics-Card-p-934367.html

It's an external gpu dock through expresscard slot (exp to pcie). I hooked it up to my PSU as shown in the video (connected 20 pin motherboard and 4 pin cpu cables). My problem is, it does not seem to fire up the PSU.

[image: http://img.banggood.com/thumb/large/2014/tanghong/07/SKU149984/SKU149984-62.jpg]

This cable connects the egpu dock with the 20 pin atx connector and 4 pin CPU power connector. But isn't something odd? How can it send the power on signal through a single cable line to 20 pin connector? Did they forget one line or is there another issue?

Comment: The line is the line for the power on signal.

Comment: Then why doesn't it "poke" the psu to turn on?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you didn't connect all the power lines.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=bP_8EYQ-2RA#t=90 At 1:30 it's clearly seen that 20 pin connector has 2 lines of cable. I'm not sure if it's possible to power on with only 1 line of cable.

Comment: It should only *need* one line; the signal ground can share with the ground in the CPU power connector.  Can you check the ATX pinout to verify the wire got mounted in the correct position on the ATX connector?